# Circle and Divs

Tags: html, css

I tried to create a small timeline. On the left circle with the year and directly on the right site the text what happend.

```
<div class="circle-singleline">
  2017
</div>
<div class="text">
  sdfs df sdfg sdf gsd fg sdf g sdfg  sdfg sdfg 
</div>

<div class="circle-singleline">
  2016
</div>
<div class="text">
  sdfs df sdfg sdf gsd fg sdf g sdfg  sdfg sdfg 
</div>
<div class="circle-singleline">
  2015
</div>
<div class="text">
  sdfs df 

sdfg sdf gsd fg sdf g sdfg  sdfg sdfg 
</div>
```

CSS

```
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css');
div {
  margin: 20px;
}

.circle-singleline {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 2px solid #646464;
  color: #000;
}

.text {
  border: 1px solid #646464;
  padding: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  left: 75px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ubgjbpog/

Now I have 2 problems:

1) how could I set up every text box on the right site to the circle?

2) how get a little arrow on the left side?

Thanks

Comment: I reckon `display: inline-block` is the droid you're looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question has several possible answers, especially when considering design approaches like the arrows you mention.  I would approach this with slightly different syntax:

```css
.circle-timeline,
.circle-timeline .item {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
}

.circle-timeline,
.circle-timeline .item,
.circle-timeline .year,
.circle-timeline .text {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.circle-timeline .item {
  margin: 10px 0;
}

.circle-timeline .year,
.circle-timeline .text {
  float: left;
  padding: 15px 0;
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.circle-timeline .year {
  text-align: center;
  width: 50px;
  border-radius: 999px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}

.circle-timeline .year:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: " ";
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  right: -6px;
  top: 40%;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 4px 0 4px 6px;
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent #cccccc;
}

.circle-timeline .text {
  padding: 5px;
  padding-left: 40px;
  margin: 10px;
  margin-left: -25px;  
  border-radius: 6px;
  width: calc(100% - 50px);
}
```

```html
<div class="circle-timeline">
 <div class="item">
  <div class="year">2017</div>
  <div class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</div>
 </div>

 <div class="item">
  <div class="year">2016</div>
  <div class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</div>
 </div>

 <div class="item">
  <div class="year">2015</div>
  <div class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</div>
 </div>
</div>
```

I'm not sure if the stylized fashion here is what you were looking for, but it uses `float` to align the year/text within each `.item` and the arrow is generated as a pseudo-class `:after`.

Comment: Thanks for that code, is it maybe possible to add jquery, that the textbox and the arrow is slide out, when you go with the mouse over the circle

Comment: You could certainly use jQuery or even CSS to animate that effect.  I'll leave that up to you - Stack Overflow is not a code-writing service so much as a code-fixing / recommendation service.

Comment: Thanks. I will try it with jquery.

Comment: `$(".year").hover(function() {
 $(this).next( ".text" ).show()
});

$(".year").mouseleave(function() {
 $( ".text" ).hide();
});` that worked. thanks

Answer (score 1):

You had position:absolute there.. That is not the best way.

Put a wrapper around each "package" and display the stuff in the wrapper as inline-block.

About the arrow I don't know what you are after but you can just add another element first in the wrapper div and then give it display: inline-block as well and it will end up to the left of the circle.

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="arrow">
    </div>
    <div class="circle-singleline">
        Inside Circle
    </div>
    <div class="text">
        Inside textBox
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper + .wrapper{
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.circle-singleline {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    font-size: 15px;
    line-height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    border: 2px solid #646464;
    color: #000;
}

.text {
   position: relative;
   display: inline-block;
   border: 1px solid #646464;
   padding: 5px;
   left: 10px;
}

.arrow{
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Working fiddle here (without arrows)
https://jsfiddle.net/ubgjbpog/4/

Answer (score 0):

> 1) how could I set up every text box on the right site to the circle?

That style you added to `.text`:

```
position: absolute;
top: 5px;
left: 75px;
```

will make all of them to be 5px from top and 75px from the left of the `body` element and be stacked on top of each other - you can notice that in your Fiddle, that's why there seems to be only one `.text` element. Using `position: absolute` in this situation is highly unadvised, due to the way it works:

> **Absolute**: 
>   The element is removed from the normal document flow; no space is created for the element in the page layout. Instead, it is positioned relative to its closest positioned ancestor if any; otherwise, it is placed relative to the initial containing block. Its final position is determined by the values of top, right, bottom, and left. This value creates a new stacking context when the value of z-index is not auto. Absolutely positioned boxes can have margins, and they do not collapse with any other margins. (Taken from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position).
>   )

In other words, if you keep using `position: absolute`, you'll have to manually adjust the positioning of each `.text` through `top` and `left`, each element will have to receive a different value, and you'll have to change it every time the content of the `.text` element changes its size. Also, this solution is not responsive at all, because different devices, browsers, etc. may render the elements differently, and all the work you had to manually position the elements might me in vain. You'll end up doing a job that CSS does very well by itself.

My best suggestion to solve this is wrap all pairs of `.circle-singleline` and `.text` in another `div`:

```
<div class="item">
    <div class="circle-singleline">2011</div>
    <div class="text">Text for 2011 goes here.</div>
</div>


<div class="item">
    <div class="circle-singleline">2012</div>
    <div class="text">Text for 2012 goes here.</div>
</div>


<div class="item">
    <div class="circle-singleline">2013</div>
    <div class="text">Text for 2013 goes here.</div>
</div>
```

And the CSS to be something like this:

```
div.item{
    margin: 20px;
    width: 100%; 
}

div.item > .circle-singleline {
    display: inline-block; 
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    font-size: 15px;
    line-height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    border: 2px solid #646464;
    color: #000;
}

div.item > .text {
    display: inline-block; 
    border: 1px solid #646464;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

As `div` elements have `display: block` by default, we add `display: inline-block` so they can be beside each other.

---

> 2) how get a little arrow on the left side?

Now that each year of your timeline has one wrapping element, you can add an `:before` to it, containing the arrow you desire, like this:

```
 div.item:before {
    display: inline;
    content:'\003E';
 }
```

Check this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ubgjbpog/7/) with all these solutions.